# Unable to add content using insertAdjacentHTML after i have successfully removed it

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```js
"use strict";

const searchBox = document.querySelector("#myText");
const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-search");
const searchContainer = document.querySelector(".search-container");
let mainText = document.querySelector(".main-text");
const quit = document.querySelector("#btn-close");
let showMain;
const newMain = "";
let printMain = function(text) {
  showMain = `
  <article class="country">
    <h1>Country you Searched</h1>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>${text}</p>
  </article>`;
  console.log(`Our show main is : ${showMain}`);
  mainText.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", showMain);
};

searchBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (searchBox.value === "Type in") {
    searchBox.value = "";
  }
});

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (searchBox.value && searchBox.value !== "Type in") {
    console.log(searchBox.value);
    printMain(searchBox.value);
    searchBox.value = "";
  } else {
    alert("please type in country name!");
  }
});

quit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //mainText.remove(showMain);
  const myDiv = document.getElementById("myId");
  const parent = myDiv.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(myDiv);
  console.log(showMain);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<header>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Simple Work</title>
  <button id="btn-close">go back</button>
</header>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <div class="main-text" id="myId"></div>
    <p class="search-container">
      <label>Type In : </label>
      <input type="text" id="myText" value="Type in" />
    </p>
    <button class="btn-search">input</button>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

So, I was trying to make code that add the text using insertAdjacentHTML
and next when I click "go back" button, it will erase the html that I had added using insertAdjacentHTML.
I have success up to this point. After this when I try to add new HTML using insertAdjacentHTML, it doesn't work. What I must do to fix this?

(as my English is second language, explanation might not be clear, I am just making web site that I could add text(must use insertAdjacentHTML) and erase that by using "go back" button and after I erase all of them, it could add new text again by using "input" button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the node, you are removing the element that `mainText` points to, therefore, you code cannot place content into a node that is no longer there. So it throws an error stating so.

You should probably only remove the element with classname of `country`:

`document.querySelector('.country').remove();`